# mysql query display wrong data?

Tags: mysql

code:

```
select * from colleges where stateid = '2' and courses like '%,BDes,%' or courses like '%,MDes,%' or courses like '%,PHDDesign,%' order by priority desc
```

Using this query I want those colleges which have stateid is 2 and courses like '%,BDes,%' or courses like '%,MDes,%' or courses like '%,PHDDesign,%'
but it display wrong data. where I am doing wrong please help me ?

Thank You

Comment: what's the output you're getting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add brakets arround the or operands:

```
select * from colleges 
where stateid = '2' and (courses like '%,BDes,%' or courses like '%,MDes,%' or courses like '%,PHDDesign,%') order by priority desc
```

But as i understand your SQL in the right way, you store data as csv which is very bad db design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your `or` conditions in a different condition brakets:

```
select * from colleges where 
      stateid = '2' and 
      (
         courses like '%,BDes,%' or 
         courses like '%,MDes,%' or 
         courses like '%,PHDDesign,%'
      )
order by priority desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition uses `AND` with multiple `OR` conditions. So the all `OR` condition must be wrapped within the brackets as

```
select * from colleges 
where stateid = 2 and (courses like '%,BDes,%' or courses like '%,MDes,%' or courses like '%,PHDDesign,%') order by priority desc
```

And is there your id column having datatype as char/varchar/text. If not, then no need to give your id inside the quotes